# Optimization: What values has to take the function?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, optimization

What value of a and b has to take the function $x^3+ax^2+bx$ in order to have a minimum at $x=4$ and an inflection point at $x=1$?

I know that the derivative of the function is $3x^2+2xa+b$ but my problem here is that I don´t know how to establish the problem.

Comment: Is the function $$3x^2+2xa+b$$ or $$x^2+ax^2+bx$$?

Comment: The second one $x^3+ax^2+bx$. The first one is the derivative.

Comment: I think you mean $x^3+\cdots$ rather than $x^2+\cdots$

Comment: Ups. Sorry, I'm fixing it.

Answer (score 0):

You are given that $f'(4)=0$ and $f''(1) = 0$. This gives you two equations for the two variables you want to solve for.

Comment: Thanks. So I need to solve the two equations as simultaneous equations?  Besides that the $b$ that the b is gone in the second derivative?

Comment: And also the $f´(4)=0$ could be a max. In order to be a min $f´´(4)>0$ right?

Comment: That's right. I'm not sure you have to use that fact though.
The fact that $b$ is not present in the second equation is not a problem, in fact it makes life a bit easier.